# Problem/Errow when opening application Growtopia CCS

Tags: .net, debugging, .net-4.8, system.configuration

When I opening an app name Growtopia auto ccs it always says like this
[Img][1]

The details:
************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

````
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>```

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPiIH.png
````

Answer (score 0):

I Alrd find the solution u just need to download visual studio with jit debugging component then just enable jit debugging at Tool>Option>Debugging>Jit-debugging (check the box, and done).

:)